# Indy TCP Server is not working from a service?

Tags: delphi, tcp, server, indy

I want to run the Indy Server from a service and I used the following code but nothing happens. When I run the service I don't receive any exceptions on starting the server but I don't receive "Connected" message either when I try to connect. Am I doing it wrong or this thing it's not possible ? The server code was tested in a normal application and it's ok, it receives connections.

I just started to learn services and I read some tutorials and they say that a very common use of a service is to check for updates for your application so I think my server should work...

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, SvcMgr, Dialogs,
  IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdCustomTCPServer, IdTCPServer, IdContext;

type
  TMarusTestService = class(TService)
    IdTCPServer1: TIdTCPServer;
    procedure ServiceExecute(Sender: TService);
    procedure ServiceStart(Sender: TService; var Started: Boolean);
    procedure ServiceStop(Sender: TService; var Stopped: Boolean);
    procedure IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
  public
    function GetServiceController: TServiceController; override;
  end;

var
  MarusTestService: TMarusTestService;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}

procedure ServiceController(CtrlCode: DWord); stdcall;
begin
  MarusTestService.Controller(CtrlCode);
end;

function TMarusTestService.GetServiceController: TServiceController;
begin
  Result := ServiceController;
end;

procedure TMarusTestService.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var f:textfile;
begin
 AssignFile(f,'f:\service.txt');
 Rewrite(f);
 Writeln(f,'Connected');
 CloseFile(f);
 repeat
  AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadLongWord;
  AContext.Connection.Socket.Write($93667B01);
 until false;
end;

procedure TMarusTestService.ServiceExecute(Sender: TService);
var f:textfile;
begin
  IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Clear;
  IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Add.SetBinding('192.168.1.2', 1280);
  try
   IdTCPServer1.Active:=True;
  except
    on E: Exception do
     begin
      AssignFile(f,'f:\service.txt');
      Rewrite(f);
      Writeln(f,'Exception: '+E.ClassName+#13+E.Message);
      CloseFile(f);
     end;
  end;

  while not Terminated do
   ServiceThread.ProcessRequests(true);
end;

procedure TMarusTestService.ServiceStart(Sender: TService;
  var Started: Boolean);
begin
  IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Clear;
  IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Add.SetBinding('192.168.1.2', 280);
  IdTCPServer1.Active:=True;
end;

procedure TMarusTestService.ServiceStop(Sender: TService; var Stopped: Boolean);
begin
  IdTCPServer1.Active:=false;
end;

end.
```

Comment: You should never ever ever do any actual service code within the main service thread. Always always always implement a separate thread to do your actual work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your service's `OnExecute` handler is wiping out the `TIdTCPServer.Binding` collection *after* the server is already activated. Just get rid of the `OnExecute` handler completely, let `TService` handle SCM requests on its own for you. Your `OnStart` handler is already activating the TCP server, that is good enough (just be sure to set `Started := True`, and `Stopped := True` in the `OnStop` event).

As for your `TIdTCPServer` events, you should move your `'Connected'` log message to the `OnConnect` event, and get rid of the loop inside the `OnExecute` event (since the event is already looped by `TIdTCPServer` for you).

Try something more like this:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, SvcMgr, Dialogs,
  IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdCustomTCPServer, IdTCPServer, IdContext,
  SyncObjs;

type
  TMarusTestService = class(TService)
    IdTCPServer1: TIdTCPServer;
    procedure ServiceCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ServiceDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ServiceStart(Sender: TService; var Started: Boolean);
    procedure ServiceStop(Sender: TService; var Stopped: Boolean);
    procedure IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
    procedure IdTCPServer1Disconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
    procedure IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
  private
    CS: TCriticalSection;
    procedure Log(const Msg: String);
  public
    function GetServiceController: TServiceController; override;
  end;

var
  MarusTestService: TMarusTestService;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}

procedure ServiceController(CtrlCode: DWord); stdcall;
begin
  MarusTestService.Controller(CtrlCode);
end;

function TMarusTestService.GetServiceController: TServiceController;
begin
  Result := ServiceController;
end;

procedure TMarusTestService.ServiceCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CS := TCriticalSection.Create;
end;

procedure TMarusTestService.ServiceDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CS.Free;
end;

procedure TMarusTestService.Log(const Msg: String);
const
  LogFileName = 'f:\service.txt';
var
  f: TextFile;
begin
  CS.Enter;
  try
    AssignFile(f, LogFileName);
    if FileExists(LogFileName) then 
      Append(f)
    else
      Rewrite(f);
    try
      WriteLn(f, '[', DateTimeToStr(Now), '] ', Msg);
    finally
      CloseFile(f);
    end;
  finally
    CS.Leave;
  end;
end;

procedure TMarusTestService.IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  Log('Connected');
end;

procedure TMarusTestService.IdTCPServer1Disconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  Log('Disconnected');
end;

procedure TMarusTestService.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadLongWord;
  AContext.Connection.Socket.Write($93667B01);
end;

procedure TMarusTestService.ServiceStart(Sender: TService; var Started: Boolean);
begin
  IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Clear;
  IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Add.SetBinding('192.168.1.2', 280, Id_IPv4);

  try
    IdTCPServer1.Active := True;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      Log('Exception: (' + E.ClassName + ') ' + E.Message);
      Win32ErrCode := 0;
      ErrCode := 1;
      Started := False;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;

  Log('Service Started');
  Started := True;
end;

procedure TMarusTestService.ServiceStop(Sender: TService; var Stopped: Boolean);
begin
  IdTCPServer1.Active := False;
  Log('Service Stopped');
  Stopped := True;
end;

end.
```